# Huawei E3131 or E1550 istallation and connection on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, huawei

I have two huawei sticks: E3131 and E1550.

I am quite new to Ubuntu 14.04, and tried loads of suggestions on this forum. But I am lost all the way. I can't make either of them install or work.

All help is welcome,

Thanks a lot